# ActiveSupport TestCase not running in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, activesupport

I'm setting up a new Sinatra app and am having issues getting my tests to run via a rake task.  When I run `rake:test`, the task runs, shows me which files it will be running, but nothing happens.  I know it's loading the class because it has failed due to syntax errors, but I never see my tests running.  What am I missing?  Below is my configuration and example test:

## rakefile.rb

```
require "rake/testtask"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require "./app"

task :default => :test

TEST_FILES = FileList["test/**/test*.rb"]

desc "Run all of the tests for redFish"
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = TEST_FILES
  t.verbose = true
end

task :default => "test"
```

## test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"

require "rack/test"
require "awesome_print"
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext"
```

## /test/unit/test_organization.rb

```
require File.expand_path '../../test_helper.rb',__FILE__

class TestOrganization < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    puts "setup for tests"
  end

  test "validates_required_fields" do
    puts "RUNNING TESTS"
    assert true
    refute false
  end
end
```

When I run `rake:test`, I can see that `test_helper` and `test_organization.rb` are being found by the TestTask, but I don't see any tests pass/fail.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was caused by not requiring `minitest/autorun` in my test helper.  I added that line, and the tests ran fine.